# How to load 36mb video in background

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube, html5-video

I want to load a video in background that is aprox 36MB.

What will be the best way to load that video without affecting the pageload speed.

I know i can do it with jQuery load function but it will still load full 36MB. Which is not good idea... Please suggest me some better way to perform this task.

Please provide me your opinions..

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two options:-

1. I Prefer to use the video hosting websites like [youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/) or [vimeo.com](https://vimeo.com/).
2. You can reduce the bitrate of your video to load the video quickly.

   I would go with first approach as i wont have to worry about the bitrate & other complex stuff.